# How can I check who created a Docker image?

Tags: docker, ownership, nvidia-docker

As in the subject, how can I check who created a certain docker image?

When I check `docker images` i don't get this information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The [recommended way in Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#maintainer-deprecated) is to set

```
LABEL maintainer "someone@example.org"
```

in your `Dockerfile`, you'll then be able to find it by using

```
docker inspect myimage:tag | grep "maintainer"
```

---

The [solution proposed by ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56948578/how-can-i-check-who-created-a-docker-image/56948600#56948600) works but it requires the deprecated [`MAINTAINER`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#maintainer-deprecated) instruction in your Dockerfile

Answer (score 3):

You can do "docker inspect" and find in the json the author information

ex:

```
$ docker inspect hello-world:latest | grep "Author"
```

Comment: +1 and -1: it works but requires `MAINTAINER` instruction in Dockerfile which is deprecated: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#maintainer-deprecated